# Passing html table data to function

Tags: javascript, php, html, function, html-table

I've used this site a ton but this is the first time posting. Please be kind. I'm trying to pass data from an HTML table to a function using onclick. I'm able to pass the entire table using `onclick="markPaid(transaction.innterText)`, but I want to be able to pass the data from the current data row only. My best attempt is `onclick="markPaid(thistransaction.innterText)"`but results in an undefined variable when passed to the function "markPaid".  Hopefully this is a clear explanation of the issue.

```
            <table id ="transaction" border="1">
            <style>th, td {padding: 10px;}</style>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th><?php echo implode('</th><th>', array_keys(current($transactions))); ?></th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php foreach ($transactions as $transaction): array_map('htmlentities', $transaction); ?>
                <tr>
                    <td id = "thistransaction"><?php echo implode('</td><td>', $transaction); ?></td>
                    <td><a class ="btn btn-default" href="invoice.php?ID=<?php echo $transaction['transid']; ?>" target = "_blank">Print Invoice</a> </td>
                    <?php if($transaction['paid'] == false): ?>
                        <td><button class = "btn btn-default" onclick="markPaid(thistransaction.innterText)">Mark as Paid</button></td>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Comment: Your `onclick` method is calling a **JavaScript** function, which has no knowledge of the database nor your PHP variables. If I understand you correctly, you're trying to update the database on click of a row. This would require your JavaScript function to post back to an independent PHP page using AJAX, passing in the row info as a `POST` argument. The PHP page would then take the info supplied in the `POST`, and use that to query the database. Hope that all makes sense :)

Comment: Yes you are absolutely correct. The javascript funcition (and ajax) will then handle the updating of the database (which i think I have figured out), but first I need to to pass the table row information to the javascript function. To your point, I may end up having to put this whole table in a form with a post method, but that's later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are getting undefined with `onclick="markPaid(thistransaction.innterText)"` because `thistransaction` is not unique. You are setting `thistransaction` as an `id` on every row of your table in your foreach loop. Try using something unique for each row, maybe the transid you echo to the invoice, `$transaction[transid]`

Comment: I could kiss you. Answer was to use `onclick="markPaid(<?php echo $transaction['transid'] ?>)"`

Comment: I'll pass on the kiss, but if you would mark my answer as the correct one that would be great :)